# Encountering "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379..." when running Google Cloud Function connecting to a Redis Instance

Tags: redis, google-cloud-functions, spring-data-redis, node-redis, google-cloud-memorystore

Im running a function to ingest data to a Redis instance. However, I am encountering an issue where I can't seem to connect to the client.

Here is the part of the code where it connects to the server.

```
const redis = require('redis');
require('dotenv').config;

        const REDISHOST = process.env.REDISHOST;
        const REDISPORT = 6379;
        const REDISAUTH = process.env.AUTHSTRING;

        const client = redis.createClient({
            port: REDISPORT,
            host: REDISHOST,
            password: REDISAUTH
        });

        await client.connect();
```

Here is the whole error message:

```
"Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1278:16)
    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)"
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

I have tried using ioredis instead of redis but it shows a different error altogether.

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to connect to localhost and Redis doesn't exist there. IF not given a hostname, this is the default behavior of Redis.

Looking at your code, this is probably because the REDISHOST environment variable isn't defined.

Comment: Indeed, this was what I missing.
In my case I needed `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

The suggested solution to the problem is to modify the code to use a URL-based connection string instead of explicitly specifying the Redis server configuration parameters. The new connection string should be in the format of:

```
redis[s]://[[username][:password]@][host][:port][/db-number]
```

Change:

```js
const client = redis.createClient({
  port: REDISPORT,
  host: REDISHOST,
  password: REDISAUTH
});
```

To:

```js
createClient({
  url: 'redis://alice:foobared@awesome.redis.server:6380'
});
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this a couple of days ago.
just use **"127.0.0.1"** instead of **"localhost"** in your **.env** file. like:

```
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
```